# how to encapsulate HTTP in a HTTPS session

Tags: security, https

Team, hi,

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me encapsulate incoming HTTP traffic, with HTTPS traffic from my application (HTTP in an iFrame), and deliver both as HTTPS.

Can Squid proxy do that?

Thanks
Etai

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use STunnel to do that.

https://www.stunnel.org